# Could be an object created on the heap treated as 'being on stack' in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Have the code:

```
struct FooBar
{
  FooBar()
  {
    MyObject obj;

    /// when c-tor is ended, obj must be deleted through d-tor call
  }
};
...
FooBar* fooBar(new FooBar);
```

`fooBar` is allocated on the heap. But object `MyObject obj` inside `FooBar`'s constructor does not know where it is created. So could be `MyObject` instantiation in the context of `FooBar` treated like it was created in the stack?

Does object allocated on the heap have its own stack? What is the size of such stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`obj` is allocated on the stack in your example (the "ordinary" stack, the "same" that is used in the code that calls `new FooBar` - assuming your environment has a stack to begin with).

The fact that `this` points to somewhere on the heap doesn't change the fact that the constructor is a (relatively) ordinary function call, and uses the same stack as other functions.

Comment: Have I got it correctly that the stack where `obj` is created and the stack where pointer to `FooBar` lives are the same?

Comment: Most likely yes. (But none of this is guaranteed by the standard - stack and heap are implementation details. You shouldn't worry about this type of detail.)

Comment: And just last moment. So in such case if MyObject, being allocated inside `FooBar` on the heap, allocates a large array `double size[1000000]` will this raise an error about insufficient [stack] memory?

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not know about stack or heap. It does know about objects with automatic and dynamic storage duration. In your case, `fooBar` has dynamic storage duration (because it is created using `new`). It will live until you call `delete` on it. `obj` has automatic storage duration (because it is not created using `new`). Its lifetime ends when the enclosing function (the `FooBar`-constructor) ends.